# How to place cursor at where I want in textView under UITest?

Tags: ios, swift, uitest

I've struggled with UITest in iOS. I want to place cursor at specific location that I want in UITextView.
So, I tried this.

```
app.textViews.typeText("#123456789")
let beginingPoint = app.textViews.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0, dy:0))
beginingPoint.tap()
```

Logic is simple. '#'is prefix. So if I write '123456789' in textview it automatically add '#' as prefix under real device.
I just put 'a123456789' under UITest and then it goes to location 1. Not 0. Is it wrong way to place cursor? help! please!